# Displaying NLCD landcover data in QGIS with landcover class type?

Tags: qgis, land-cover, nlcd

I am trying to display land cover layer (.tif) into QGIS. But some reason the layer appears in grayscale when I load in QGIS (Figure 1). I am expecting to see the somewhat similar display as in ArcMap (Figure 2). In QGIS, when I looked into the layer's properties, the Singelband gray is a default Band rendering for this layer. I wonder how can I display the layer as in AcrMap or is there steps in QGIS to process the layer to look like in Figure 2.

I'm using
QGIS 2.14.3-Essen
OS: Windows 8

[image: Figure 1: Looks grayscale in QGIS] Figure 1

[image: Layer View]

[image: Figure 2: Same layer displayed in ArcMap] Figure 2

[image]

Answer (score 4):

New user without the karma to comment on the above answer — but here's a Github Gist with a QGIS style / .qml file I made based on the above information (it looks like @StuSmith's link no longer works): https://gist.github.com/eidietrich/b069eeead2b542caa7c6d43d3eaf8699

Should be loadable via Layer Properties >> Symbology >> Style >> Load Style.

Comment: This is PERFECT!

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I enable color:

1. Drop-down Render Type to "Singleband pseudocolor"
2. Drop-down Color and select one of the color ramps.
3. Click the "Classify" button
4. Click "Apply"

But more importantly, you probably want to match the NLCD colors:

[image]

Here's what I did:

1. Download the NLCD data from: http://www.landfire.gov/bulk/downloadfile.php?TYPE=nlcd2011&FNAME=nlcd_2011_landcover_2011_edition_2014_10_10.zip
2. Unzip
3. Add the NLCD .img raster layer into QGIS.  Here's what I get, which by default has the correct NLCD symbology:
   [image]

If you would like to save the NLCD style for later use in QGIS, open the NLCD layer properties and click the Style tab. Again, here's what I get:
[image]

Click the Style dropdown and select "Save Style...".   The saved .qml file can be used later on other projects requiring NLCD colors: click the Style dropdown and select "Load Style..", and select the previously saved.qml file.  Voila!  NLCD colors.

Comment: @ Stu Smith,Thanks ! The problem I face with the Singleband pseudocolor is I can't set the unique class code for each land cover classes. Example, I used the "Classify" to symbolize 8 different classes using its class code value but I don't find the option to keep the class unique other than Continuous, Equal interval and Quantile.  Another thing, eventually I wanted to see all land cover class label automatically displayed under the Layer Panel instead of its class code.

Comment: @StuSmith, I ran into a similar issue as the OP.  Do you have any suggestions?  Or perhaps even a QML file you can share?  I asked a similar question at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259389/how-to-read-a-raster-value-table-vat-in-qgis

Comment: @Ryandalton I don't know how to attach a .qml file to this thread, so I uploaded ncld.qml to https://www.dropbox.com/preview/Public/nlcd.qml?role=personal