# QGIS: Cropland Data Layer - how to add class names to .tif file?

Tags: classification, qgis-2.18

I'm working with a clip of the Cropland Data Layer (raster), which has a number for each value coded to a crop type. I want to add these crop type / class names to the .tif file (and have them show up in the "Identify Results" pane). the CDL has a nice explanation for doing this in ArcGIS:

> f your downloaded CDL .tif file does not contain category names, then you can add them using the following instructions. Download the file: generic_cdl_attributes.tif.vat.dbf. This generic file contains all possible CDL colors and category names. As long as the .tif file and the .tif.vat.dbf file have the same file name, then the category names will load automatically in ArcMap. So, change the file name (not extension) of the generic_cdl_attributes.tif.vat.dbf to match the file name of the downloaded CDL .tif file. Then add the .tif file as a layer in ArcMap. The category names will display in the Table of Contents window.

I have tried this method in QGIS but can't get it to work. Here's a screenshot showing that only the value, not the class, is displayed in the "identify results" pane:
[image: no class]

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259389/how-to-read-a-raster-value-table-vat-in-qgis a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32803/accessing-raster-attribute-table-in-qgis ?